# Automatically Scroll to rendered element after setState in React.js

Tags: reactjs

Suppose i have some setState declarations on list items on top of page as follows:

```
<DropdownMenu >
    <DropdownItem className="channel-setting__btn"
      onClick={() => this.setState({ facebookFields: true, youtubeFields: true })}>All</DropdownItem>

    <DropdownItem
      className="channel-setting__btn"
      onClick={() => this.setState({ facebookFields: true, youtubeFields: false })}>Facebook
    </DropdownItem>

    <DropdownItem
      className="channel-setting__btn"
      onClick={() => this.setState({ facebookFields: false, youtubeFields: true })}>Youtube
    </DropdownItem>

</DropdownMenu>
```

Is there any way that when ever i click on DropDownItem then whatever the DOM Element has rendered the page automatically scrolls smoothly to that section or wherevever the element has rendered on page, in this cas the Elements are Different forms for facebook and youtube which will render at the very end and far too close to the end of page.

Comment: check out [react-scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll), even if you don't require the package, you'll get an idea of how to implement animated scrolling. [scroller.js](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll/blob/master/modules/mixins/scroller.js) is where the scrolling is implemented

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `scrollIntoView` function after `componentDidUpdate` which is called immediately after `render`.

Here is a version using ID of the element to be scrolled to. You can also store the `refs` of the element and do it the react recommended way. (You are not modifying the DOM in anyway)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      media: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      media: event.target.value
    });
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const element = document.getElementById(this.state.media);
    
    element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <select value={this.state.media} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
          <option value="youtube">Youtube</option>
        </select>
        <p id="facebook" className="social-media">Facebook</p>
        <p id="youtube" className="social-media">Youtube</p>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.social-media {
  height: 100vh;
}

#facebook {
  margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You might want to check the browser support of scrollIntoView and include a [polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll).

Comment: thanx man. exactly what i was looking for. didn't knew about "ComponentDidUpdate" method in react.

Comment: hi there, i am having another issue now. there is another method which is called whenever i click on toggle button 
`toggleSchedule = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      scheduling: !value
    });
  }`
now when i click the toggle button the page is again scrolling i guess this is because componentDidUpdate is being called because the view of toogle button changes. I tried prevState in componentDidUpdate(prevState) like so, which console logged and this is what i am getting in prevState --> `{match: {…}, location: {…}, history: {…}, staticContext: undefined}`.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` receives the `prevState` as an argument, you can cross check that with current state to find if the state update is triggered by the dropdown.

Comment: thats is what i am trying to do but when is console.log(prevState) i get this: 
`{match: {…}, location: {…}, history: {…}, staticContext: undefined}`
which seems like react router's things.

Comment: @SushmitGaur That is probably because you are checking `prevProps` and not `prevState`. `prevState` is the second argument to `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: no i am just passing prevState in componentDidUpdate, like so:
`componentDidUpdate(prevState)`

Comment: That is the problem. It is `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` only if you have a second argument is it state.

Comment: Got it buddy. thanx.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways to do this:
One of the way is to listen to the change of state in componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle event as:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProp, nextState){
   //considering only first case here
   if (nextState.facebookFields== true && youtubeFields ==true){
      setTimeout(function(){
         let objControl=document.getElementById("theIdOfTheElementToBeRendered");
         objControl.scrollIntoView();
      },500)
   }
}
```

As you see above, I have used setTimeout, because at this time the element is not rendered. The callback function will be called back once the rendering will happen (I assumed a 500ms delay; you can decide yourself).

I have used plain old JS to scroll to the element. Make sure the element has a unique id.

Hope this answer helps you. I am open for discussion. Regards.